# Compare Types using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm getting this error:

> incomparable types: Class and String   where CAP#1 is a fresh
>   type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?

```
Object object;
Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
   if (fields[i].getType() == String) { //On this line the compiler error is displayed
        //Can't get in here            
   }
}
```

I thought I was comparing two of the same classes in that `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) returns a class so you must compare it with a `Class`.  To get the class for `String` you must use `String.class`.

```
if (fields[i].getType() == String.class) {
        //Now you can get in here!            
}
```